# Variable filename in Java

Tags: java, loops, filenames, printwriter

Is there any way you can change the name of a file each time doing a loop?
Lets say I've got the following sample code:

```
while(somecondition) {    
    try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");){
        w.println("Bye World");
    } 
}
```

Now i want to change the name of output.txt each time the loop starts again to output++.txt.

I would now receive:

```
output1.txt
output2.txt
output3.txt
outputn.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n && someCondition; i++) {    
    try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("output" + i + ".txt", "UTF-8");){
        w.println("Bye World");
    } 
}
```

Comment: `i < n && someCondition` may be what the OP wants (unless someCondition is already a counter).

Comment: @assylias: I figured this was the `someCondition`. You might be right though.

Comment: I just wanted to know this part of the code: "output" + i + ".txt" ,did not know it is that simple. The condition wasnt relevant so i named it somecondition to simplify it.